# Is this directory Structure good enough for Selenium Test + C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

I am writing Selenium tests using Visual Studio C# Express edition 2010. 
I was trying to find if some one is already posted directory structure for Selenium tests. 
Not having found one I created my own. I Curious to know how I could improve on it.

Comment: Wonder how I attach file, I have posted image of directory here - https://picasaweb.google.com/tkumarb/CSeleniumTests#5595689317355107762

Comment: I ended up in following this -

https://picasaweb.google.com/tkumarb/CSeleniumTests#

and namespace would be named as -

namespace ComppanyName.Tests
{

    class CreateAccount

Is it any better?

##########################
On a different note, did you support Selenium Proposal on area51 -
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4693/selenium
You just need to click Commit button to support site, while having
logged using your Google/Yahoo account.
This proposal is backed by SeleniumHQ and we need more users to commit
to it to make it see day of light.
#########################

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used http://code.google.com/p/design-of-selenium-tests-for-asp-net/ as the basis for my c# selenium tests. Although it's a little framework on top of selenium 1 you can easily switch it to selenium 2.

Answer (score 0):

I work in Eclipse-Java environment, I have a "lib" folder inside my workspace, where I store all the external jar files(API's like jxl, selenium client etc.). I think you can add this folder in your Project to include selenium's C# driver and reference it from this location in your build path.

Comment: I am pretty comfortable with java part of Selenium. I really want to hear from some one who has worked and is working on Selenium C# driver, and how they manage their directory structure.